# Trouble testing AJAX calls using xampp

Tags: javascript, ajax, xampp

I'm trying to setup my laptop to be able to test java scripts, in particular in need to be able to make AJAX calls to .csv/.tsv files.

To do this I have setup xampp and moved my files to the xampp directory. Will I need to do anything else (e.g. configuration) to be able to open the .html file saved in the xampp directory and have it be able to make AJAX calls. When I do this I still get the usual "same origin" error.

I know that the code should work as I am trying to reproduce one of the d3 examples to see if the server works.

Would anyone be able to point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you browse to to http://127.0.0.1/ to navigate your files ?

Comment: did you start the server? do you load your webside through http://localhost/yourside?